# Doing asynchronous socket and file io in D (node.js style)

Tags: d

What is the D way to do the async io? I am talking about select/epoll based single(mostly)threaded operations.

I am considering to link to lib_uv and then program in C style, (or maybe write some neat classes around lib_uv calls), but is that the best option?

What I am looking to do something like:

```cpp
// pseudo code

Server server;
server.listen(address, port, callback);

void callback(Error error, Socket socket){
   if (! error) {
      socket.write(data, another_callback);
      socket.bind.on_data(data_received_callback);
   }
   else writeln("connection failed");
}
```

Comment: http://vibed.org/ is the thing typically posted about this. It has an async lib wrapped with a fiber lib so you call their functions linearally and it transforms it into async to avoid too many layers of callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

As Adam already stated: [Vibe.d](http://vibed.org) is an awesome library and usually the best option for asynchronous programming in D.
As a short introduction for others who might find this question in the future, here's a minimal example of Vibe.d that serves files.

Note that routes in Vibe.d are fibers and (most) Vibe.d functions are asynchronous. For example, while a file is read the execution is yielded to the next fiber in the event queue and resumed once the OS send backs the requested data.
Moreover, Vibe.d already provides built-in functionality for serving files (see `/b`) which allows to request only a [partial content](https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/) of a file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env dub
/+ dub.sdl:
name "mini_vibed"
dependency "vibe-d" version="~>0.7.30"
versions "VibeDefaultMain"
+/

import vibe.d;

shared static this()
{
    auto settings = new HTTPServerSettings;
    settings.port = 8080;

    auto router = new URLRouter;
    router.get("/a", (scope req, scope res) {
        auto inStream = openFile(__FILE_FULL_PATH__);
        res.bodyWriter.write(inStream);
    });
    router.get("/b", serveStaticFile(__FILE_FULL_PATH__));
    router.get("*", (scope req, scope res) {
        res.writeBody("Please try /a or /b");
    });

    listenHTTP(settings, router);
}
```

Either `chmod +x` this file and run it or use `dub --single <file>`.

If you just want to do asynchronous programming, have a look into [vibe.core.concurrency](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.core.concurrency).

You can explore more examples at [Vibe.d's GitHub page](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/vibe.d/tree/master/examples).